# Permutations in Haskell involving List Comprehensions, Recursion and the delete function

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension, permutation

I'm a Haskell beginner following exercises from a book. The first question asked me to define a function that deletes the first occurrence of an integer from a list of integers.

E.g.

```
delete 5 [1,5,3,5,1]
```

outputs:

```
[1,3,5,1]
```

The second question asks me to create a function that uses the delete function I just defined, that takes as an argument a list of integers, and outputs a list of all the permutations as lists.

E.g.

```
perms [1,2,3]
```

outputs:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

I tried hard, gave up and googled the solution.

Here's what I found:

```
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = [ i:j | i <- xs, j <- perms $ delete i xs ]
```

I looked around and found many other similar solutions, almost identical, just using different variable names and parentheses instead of the `$` symbol, so I'm guessing this is a common problem with an idiomatic solution.

I'm just a little lost trying to understand exactly what this code is doing. I am seeking a step by step explanation through the recursion, to understand how this code is creating a list of permutations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any recursive function that operates on lists, this one can be broken down into two cases:

1) What should the function do on an empty list?

2) If I know what the function does on a list of length `n`, can I use that to figure out what the function should do on a list of length `n + 1`.

Once you know those two things, you have a definition that will work on any list (at least one of finite length - such a procedure will of course never end for one of infinite length; that doesn't matter here as it doesn't make much sense to talk about permutations from an infinite list). [If you have any sort of mathematical background, you will recognise this as a simple statement of the law of [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).]

For the `perms` function, it is clear that there is only one way to permute the 0 elements of the empty list: another empty list. This gives `[[]]` for the base case, as in the first line of the example solution.

For the recursive/inductive step, let's say we have a list `xs` of length `n` (where `n > 0`), and suppose (as we are allowed to) that we already know how to compute all permutations of any list of length `n - 1`.

Each permutation must start with a particular element of the `xs` - let's call this element `i`, and think about how to get all the permutations of `xs` whose first element is `i`. It should be clear that these correspond precisely with all permutations of the list `delete i xs` (that is, `xs` with one `i` removed) - given a permutation `j` of the latter, the list `i : j` is a permutation of `xs` which begins with `i`, and conversely all such permutations of `xs` can be obtained in that way.

Note that this is exactly the list `[ i:j | j <- perms $ delete i xs ]`

(And note in passing that, since we've assumed `i` is in `xs`, `delete i xs` indeed has length `n - 1`, so by the inductive hypothesis we know how to compute this.)

`i` of course was chosen completely arbitrarily there - and *all* elements of `xs` will need to be accounted for as the first element of some permutations. So we simply put together all of the above, for all elements `i` in `xs` - which is exactly what the expression in the recursive step is:

```
[ i:j | i <- xs, j <- perms $ delete i xs ]
```

You might need to read some of the above slowly, a few times, before it makes sense - but it is fundamentally very elementary logic (and like most elementary logic, has a nasty habit of often looking more complicated than it actually is).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

- One by one take a single element `i` from `xs`
- Delete `i` from `xs` and prepend `i` to `j` (every list element of the `perms` of `xs` less `i`) up until all `i`s are depleted.